# How to link Google Cloud App Engine Web app to Google Compute engine VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have successfully deployed my Java web application on GCP App Engine, and successfully connected it with Cloud SQL.
Then I want to link the web app with GoDaddy DNS Zone configuration, so that I can access the app with my registered host name, for this, as per You tube videos, I have created a GCP Compute engine VM instance and generated the NameSpaces(*Note: the VM instance IP is static*) and configured them in GoDaddy DNS configurations. After that when I try to access the app using the host name, It is simply saying that the app is refused to connect.
Then I realised that there is no link between the App Engine instance and Compute engine instance.
I guess I did wrong but, what should I do to correct it, without redeployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, it seems there is no need to use a Compute Engine instance to sit between your GAE app and your users.

Check out [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) where it is well explained what steps you need to follow. It basically involves:

1. proving Google that you own/manage the domain you want to use and
2. map that domain (in GoDaddy's DNS Manager) to your App Engine app